# ESP32S: More than two SPI channels possible?

Tags: spi, camera, esp32

In a test with an [ESP32-CAM](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeeedDocument/forum_doc/master/reg/ESP32_CAM_V1.6.pdf), I was successfully able to use SPI with pins 2, 12, 14, and 15:

```
#define GPIO_MOSI 2
#define GPIO_MISO 12
#define GPIO_SCLK 14
#define GPIO_CS 15
```

However, I cannot run the camera in parallel with my additional SPI communication. The problem are *not* the pins. Pins 2, 12, 14, and 15 are *not* used by the camera. The problem is the following line in my code:

```
spi_slave_initialize(HSPI_HOST, &buscfg, &slvcfg, 1);
```

If I switch to `HSPI_HOST`, then again the camera won't start. The camera on the ESP32-CAM uses both SPI channels, `HSPI` and `VSPI`. The module is built around an [ESP32S](https://www.es.co.th/Schemetic/PDF/ESP32.PDF).

*On the ESP32S, is there a third channel that I can use?*

Notes:

- The ESP-EYE, another ESP32 based board with a camera, can do SPI communication while the camera is running. This I have tested. The ESP-EYE is more expensive, though, and it is hard to connect to a board. I will need a few dozen ESP32 based camera modules.
- Communication speed can be low, 1200 baud would be more than enough.

Comment: You should be able to bit-bang SPI at that speed.

Comment: @RonBeyer Indeed, I was just pointed to the [ulp-spi](https://github.com/espressif/esp-iot-solution/tree/master/examples/ulp_examples/ulp_spi) example, which shows exactly that.